# Android Widget Button Click Toast Maessage

Tags: android, button, android-widget, widget, toast

I've created a simple widget have only a button and textView. When I add my widget first time to the homescreen a FC message coming and widget will added. And button click toast message won't work. Only i need to have a toast message when clicking the widget button. I've gone through lots of tutorials but couldn't figure out whats the problem. Any genius who'd like to help..really appriciate the help..Thanks..

widgetProvider.java

```
public class widgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider{

    @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, widgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver android:name=".widgetProvider" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter >
            <action 
                android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widgetprovider" />
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: first, what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Message is "Unfortunately, A_Widget has stopped." but widget will added to homescreen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your onUpdate is never called since you overriden the onReceive method.

Comment: Thanks for the help..but pardon me..how do I do that..How do I call onUpdate before onReceive.

Comment: if it's not you action then you should call `super.onReceive` . Also, I think that you have an exception because the intent's action can be null.

Comment: @rzshss can you please provide the updated code that worked? I really need it. Thanks in advance